# Differentiate Window vs Page vs UserControl in WPF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, windowsformshost

I wondered if someone could help me. I'm new to WPF and am currently writing a desktop application, but I cannot seem to get my head around what to use when redirecting someone to a new section of the application.

My options appear to be

```
Window
Page
UserControl
```

but I don't understand what the difference between them is, and when I should use each one.

Could someone explain the differences for me, and give an example of what situations/applications you may use each one for?

Comment: Exactly same question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206120/window-vs-page-vs-usercontrol-for-wpf-navigation

Comment: See also question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025504/should-i-be-using-a-page-window-or-usercontrol for great answear.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure there is a *right answer* here, but let me try and guide you. The `Window` class was created to allow you to have a true window. So, if you need to open a dialog, put it in a `Window`. Generally you will have *at least one* `Window` to house the main form.

A `Page` was built to be used with the `NavigationWindow` class. This allows you to build `Page` classes that are marked up like everything else, but just navigate to them under the covers. This is good if you have a single-paged application where the users just go back and forth between pages (i.e. a wizard).

A `UserControl` is a way to house reusable markup. These can be housed inside of any `ContentControl`. These can be swapped out of a "content pane" for example on the main window, like Outlook.

Using that, I hope it helps guide you in the right direction on when to use which. They each have their own uses and are not necessarily exclusive.